# How to guarantee message ordering over multiple topics in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, event-driven

I am creating a system in which I use kafka as an event store. The problem I am having is not being able to guarantee the message ordering of all the events.

Let's say I have a User entity and a Order entity. Right now I have the topics configured as follows:

- user-deleted
- user-created
- order-deleted
- order-created

When consuming these topics from the start (when a new consumer group registers) first the user-deleted topic gets consumed then the user-created etc. The problem with this is that the events over multiple topics do not get consumed chronologically, only within the topic.

Let's say 2 users get created and after this one gets deleted. The result would be one remaing user.

Events:

1. user-created
2. user-created
3. user-deleted

My system would consume these like:

1. user-deleted
2. user-created
3. user-created

Which means the result is 2 remaining users which is wrong.

I do set the partition key (with the user id) but this seems only to guarantee order within a topic. How does this problem normally get tackled?
I have seen people using topic per entity. Resulting in 2 topics for this example (user and order) but this can still cause issues with related enities.

Comment: can you like deal with the user_created event and then deal with the user_deleted?

Comment: @wuhoyt That wouldn't work because there might be events consumed for created users after a timestamp which the user_deleted topic has an event for some user. The topics would need consumed in parallel, if not read the full user_deleted topic into memory, then join the created users against it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've designed is ["request/response topics"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/21/event-driven-topic-design-using-kafka/), and you cannot order between multiple topics this way.

Instead, design "entity topics" or "event topics". This way, ordering will be guaranteed, and you only need one topic per entity. For  example,

### Topic `users`

For a `key=userId`, you can structure events this way.

#### Creates

```
userId, {userId: userId, name:X, ...}
```

#### Updates

```
userId, {userId: userId, name:Y, ...}
```

#### Deletes

```
userId, null
```

Use a compacted topic for an event-store such that all deletes will be tombstoned and dropped from any materialized view.

---

You could go a step further and create a wrapper record.

```
userId, {action:CREATE, data:{name:X, ...}}  // full-record
userId, {action:UPDATE, data:{name:Y}}       // partial record
userId, {action:DELETE}                      // no data needed
```

This topic acts as your "event entity topic", but then, you need a stream processor to parse and process these events consistently into the above format, such as null-ing any `action:DELETE`, and writing to a compacted topic (perhaps automatically using Kafka Streams KTable)

Comment: Thank you. After applying this solution it works.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka is not able to maintain ordering across multiple topics. It's not capable either to maintain ordering inside one topic that has several partitions. The only ordering guarantee we have is within each partition of one topic.

What this means is that if the order of `user-created` and `user-deleted` as known by a kafkfa producer must be the same as the order of those events as perceived by a kafka consumer (which is understandable as you explain), then those events must be sent to same kafka partition of the same topic.

Usually, you don't actually need the whole order to be exactly the same for the producer and producer (i.e. you don't need *total ordering*), but you need it to be the same at least for each entity id, i.e. for each user id the `user-created` and `user-deleted` event must be in the same order for the producer and the consumer, but it's often acceptable to have events mixed up across users (i.e. you need _partial ordering`).

In practice this means you must use the same topic for all those events, which means this topic will contain events with different schemas.

One strategy for achieving that is to use union types, i.e. you declare in your event schema that the type can either be a `user-created` or a `user-deleted`. Both [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Unions) and [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof) offer this feature.

Another strategy, if you're using Confluent Schema registry, is to allow a topic to be associated with several types in the registry, using the `RecordNameStrategy` schema resolution strategy. The blog post [Putting Several Event Types in the Same Topic – Revisited](https://www.confluent.io/blog/multiple-event-types-in-the-same-kafka-topic/) is probably a good source of information for that.

Comment: As far as aI understand it you and @OneCricketeer are talking about the same thing. Applying this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feed-back, glad to hear this was useful